# How To Fetch MySQL table data into Data tables via CodeIgniter and Ajax not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to perform CRUD operation with code igniter & ajax methodology. There is an existing open source application called "OSPOS". i have created an new module for performing CRUD but facing issue in retrieving data from db table via ajax request

On document ready i have called a function in which get request is made to controller function to fetch and load data into my data tables. unable to identify problem

On page load this function is being called

```
function listExpense(){
        $.ajax({
            type  : 'ajax',
            url   : 'expense/show',
            async : false,
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data){
                var html = '';
                var i;
                for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                    html += '<tr id="'+data[i].id+'">'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].id+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].type+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].amount+'</td>'+                              
                            '<td>'+data[i].description+'</td>'+
                            '<td style="text-align:center;">'+
                                '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info btn-sm editRecord" data-id="'+data[i].id+'" data-type="'+data[i].type+'" data-amount="'+data[i].amount+'" data-description="'+data[i].description+'">Edit</a>'+' '+
                                '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteRecord" data-id="'+data[i].id+'">Delete</a>'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '</tr>';
                }
                $('#listRecords').html(html);                   
            }
        });
    }
```

---

This is controller file

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once("Persons.php");

class Expense extends Persons
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('expense');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('expense/manage');
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $this->load->model('Expense');

        $data = $this->Expense->saveExpense();
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

    public function show()
    {
        $this->load->model('Expense');

        $data = $this->Expense->expenseList();
        echo json_encode($data);
    }   
}
?>

-------------------------

This is model file

<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Expense extends Person
{   
    public function saveExpense()
    {
        $data = array(              
                'type' => $this->input->post('type'), 
                'amount' => $this->input->post('amount'), 
                'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
            );

        $result = $this->db->insert('ospos_expense',$data);
        return $result;
    }

    function expenseList()
    {
        $list = $this->db->get('ospos_expense');
        return $list->result();
    }
}
?>
```

---

This is person.php file

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once("Secure_Controller.php");

abstract class Persons extends Secure_Controller
{
    public function __construct($module_id = NULL)
    {
        parent::__construct($module_id);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['table_headers'] = $this->xss_clean(get_people_manage_table_headers());

        $this->load->view('people/manage', $data);
    }

    /*
     Gives search suggestions based on what is being searched for
    */
    public function suggest()
    {
        $suggestions = $this->xss_clean($this->Person->get_search_suggestions($this->input->post('term')));

        echo json_encode($suggestions);
    }

    /*
    Gets one row for a person manage table. This is called using AJAX to update one row.
    */
    public function get_row($row_id)
    {
        $data_row = $this->xss_clean(get_person_data_row($this->Person->get_info($row_id), $this));

        echo json_encode($data_row);
    }

    /*
    Capitalize segments of a name, and put the rest into lower case.
    You can pass the characters you want to use as delimiters as exceptions.
    The function supports UTF-8 string.

    Example:
        i.e. <?php echo nameize("john o'grady-smith"); ?>

        returns John O'Grady-Smith
    */

    protected function nameize($string)
    {
        return str_name_case($string);
    }
}
?>
```

---

This is Secure controller file

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Secure_Controller extends CI_Controller 
{
    /*
    * Controllers that are considered secure extend Secure_Controller, optionally a $module_id can
    * be set to also check if a user can access a particular module in the system.
    */
    public function __construct($module_id = NULL, $submodule_id = NULL)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('Employee');
        $model = $this->Employee;

        if(!$model->is_logged_in())
        {
            redirect('login');
        }

        $this->track_page($module_id, $module_id);

        $logged_in_employee_info = $model->get_logged_in_employee_info();
        if(!$model->has_module_grant($module_id, $logged_in_employee_info->person_id) || 
            (isset($submodule_id) && !$model->has_module_grant($submodule_id, $logged_in_employee_info->person_id)))
        {
            redirect('no_access/' . $module_id . '/' . $submodule_id);
        }

        // load up global data visible to all the loaded views
        $data['allowed_modules'] = $this->Module->get_allowed_modules($logged_in_employee_info->person_id);
        $data['user_info'] = $logged_in_employee_info;
        $data['controller_name'] = $module_id;

        $this->load->vars($data);
    }

    /*
    * Internal method to do XSS clean in the derived classes
    */
    protected function xss_clean($str, $is_image = FALSE)
    {
        // This setting is configurable in application/config/config.php.
        // Users can disable the XSS clean for performance reasons
        // (cases like intranet installation with no Internet access)
        if($this->config->item('ospos_xss_clean') == FALSE)
        {
            return $str;
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->security->xss_clean($str, $is_image);
        }
    }

    protected function track_page($path, $page)
    {
        if(get_instance()->Appconfig->get('statistics'))
        {
            $this->load->library('tracking_lib');

            if(empty($path))
            {
                $path = 'home';
                $page = 'home';
            }

            $this->tracking_lib->track_page('controller/' . $path, $page);
        }
    }

    protected function track_event($category, $action, $label, $value = NULL)
    {
        if(get_instance()->Appconfig->get('statistics'))
        {
            $this->load->library('tracking_lib');

            $this->tracking_lib->track_event($category, $action, $label, $value);
        }
    }

    public function numeric($str)
    {
        return parse_decimals($str);
    }

    public function check_numeric()
    {
        $result = TRUE;

        foreach($this->input->get() as $str)
        {
            $result = parse_decimals($str);
        }

        echo $result !== FALSE ? 'true' : 'false';
    }


    // this is the basic set of methods most OSPOS Controllers will implement
    public function index() { return FALSE; }
    public function search() { return FALSE; }
    public function suggest_search() { return FALSE; }
    public function view($data_item_id = -1) { return FALSE; }
    public function save($data_item_id = -1) { return FALSE; }
    public function delete() { return FALSE; }

}
?>
```

if i create separate files other than this open source software code, My code works fine but issue arises once i try to integrate my code into this open source application i.e "OSPOS"

Comment: Please check the console for AJAX Request and see what error is there.

Comment: AJAX http://example.com/public/expense/show 500 (Internal Server Error). expense is contoller and show is the function to fetch db table contents. As per console it says this URL has issue

Comment: when this url is directly run in browser it gives HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: public function show()
 {
  $this->load->model('Expense');
  
  $data = $this->Expense->expenseList();
  echo json_encode($data);
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function listExpense(){
    $.ajax({
        type  : 'ajax',
        url   : 'expense/show',
        async : false, 
        success : function(data){
             $('#listRecords').html(data);           
        }
    });
    }
</script>
<?php 
 public function show()
    {
        $this->load->model('Expense');

        $data = $this->Expense->expenseList();
        if($data!=NULL)
        {
            foreach($data as $value)
            {
                ?>
                <tr id="<?= $value['id'];?>">
                    <td><?= $value['id'];?></td>
                    <td><?= $value['type'];?></td>
                    <td><?= $value['amount'];?></td>
                    <td><?= $value['description'];?></td>
                    <td>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info btn-sm editRecord" data-id="<?= $value['id'];?>" data-type="<?= $value['type'];?>" data-amount="<?= $value['amount'];?>" data-description="<?= $value['description'];?>">Edit</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteRecord" data-id="<?= $value['id'];?>">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function listExpense(){
    $.ajax({
        type  : 'POST',
        url   : 'expense/show', 
        cache: true,
        success : function(data){
             $('#listRecords').html(data);           
        }
    });
    }
</script>
```